# can we use log4j in mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-partitioning

Can we use log4j to log in mapreduce? If so, provide the steps to use log4j in map-reduce to log the information. I have written the below log4.properties but, nothing was logged.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple way to configure the Log4j in Mapper, just for

[Standard practices for logging in MapReduce jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119423/standard-practices-for-logging-in-mapreduce-jobs)

and the code snippet goes here

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
// other imports omitted

public class SampleMapper extends Mapper {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SampleMapper.class);

```
@Override
protected void setup(Context context) {
    logger.info("Initializing NoSQL Connection.")
    try {
        // logic for connecting to NoSQL - ommitted
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // mapper code ommitted
}
```

}

Sorry for formatting.